# Insert a result from a stored procedure in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, insert-into

I'm trying to understand how to deal with procedures in Postgresql.

I get the idea of creating a function that returns a variable. What I don't get is how I can use such variable, for instance, in an insert.

Imagine this, I have a function called getName(), that returns a variable $name$.

What I want is to insert such variable in another table... How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function returns a single value, you can use it anywhere a constant could be used.

```
insert into some_table (id, name)
values (42, get_name());
```

this is the same as using a built-in function:

```
insert into some_table (id, modified_at)
values (42, now());
```

It can be used the same way in an `update` statement

```
update some_table
  set name = get_name()
where id = 42;
```

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking I had to create some temp variable or something, but i can call it directly, like you said values(42, get_name()); Thanks a lot! :)